# Retrieve decimals only from a variable

Tags: string, actionscript-3

I'm making a distance/time used calculator where i'm trying to separate whole hours and minutes.

Code:

```
if (hours >= 1)
{
    minutes = Number((hours-int.(hours))*60);
    timeTxt.text = String(int.(hours)+" hours & "+(minutes)+" minutes");
}
else
{
    timeTxt.text = String((hours*60).toFixed(0)+" minutes");
}
```

the "else" one is working and prints minutes only. But I can't get the first if statement to work. Trying to print "x hours & x minutes".

Getting this message in output:

TypeError: Error #1123: Filter operator not supported on type class int.
    at Rutekalkulator2_fla::MainTimeline/calculate()

Comment: What is `int.(hours)` supposed to be? If you're trying to cast `hours` into int, then you want `((int) hours)` instead.

Comment: Trying to retrieve minutes only by taking hours (with decimals) and substracting whole hours only by using int(hours) if that works then multiply by 60. Example if hours = 3,73: minutes =Number(3,73 - int(3,73))*60;

Comment: Using ((int) hours) instead of int.(hours) seems to have worked. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Another way to solve this, without any math, is to make a `string` out of `hours` through a temporary variable. Then you can check with `indexOf` if a `,` character exists and extract the substrings of both sides.

Comment: And you should also check if casting `hours` into an `int` will round it (3.7 would turn into a 4 for example), which probably is not your intention.

Comment: Traced all the values and it doesnt round it, just removes the decimals. 1.9 for example still becomes 1. Think I will stick to this solution as I don't have so much time, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do something like:
(pseudocode)

double tmp = math.floor(yournumber);
yournumber = yournumber - tmp;

And that'll make your number be just the decimal part.

Besides that, I'm not really sure what your question is.

Answer (score -1):

Convert everything to minutes then try the following:

```
timeTxt.text = String( totMinutes / 60 + ":" + totMinutes % 60);
// output 06:36

timeTxt.text = String( totMinutes / 60 + " hours and " + totMinutes % 60 + " minutes");
// output 6 hours and 36 minutes
```

I'm not fluent in Actionscript but if the modulo works the same as it does in other languages this should work for you.